# cuda cannot find lXmu

Tags: netbeans, cuda

I get this error

> cuda cannot find lXmu

while compiling cuda-5.0/Samples with

```
sudo make LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

?

Answer (score 1):

simple:

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev libxmu6
```